# Python function return to jQuery var

Tags: jquery, python

I've a python script that returns something. In a html page, I use jQuery to send a GET request to this script (with $.get()). I want the "return" of python script in a jQuery/javascript var. Is it possible with jQuery function? Without use JSON or other.

Comment: What kind of data is the script returning?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("url", function (response) { 
  var myVar = response;
  // Do stuff with variable here
});
```

If the response contains HTML, you can use $(response) to get a jquery object to do operations on, but the response object itself is already a string.

Comment: To access to myVar outside $.get() function?

Comment: And if python script returns a list, it's the same?

Comment: If you want to access myVar outside of the get-function, you have to declare it before the function. And if python returns a list, jQuery - or better JavaScript - either doesn't know what to do with it, or it simply parses it as a string.

Comment: If I declare myVar before the function, when I use it outside, I obtain undefined value.

Comment: That's why I said do all your actions with the variable inside the callout function.  Otherwise you have to come up with some other way to ensure the data has been retrieved before you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the dataType parameter to HTML.  So in the below example return_value is a text representation of whatever is returned by your python script

```
$.get('http://wwww.example.com/',function(data){
var return_value = data;
}, 'html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is a wonderful thing. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Specifically you want the fourth example.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you say "without using JSON"? That's exactly what JSON is for.